# Use a constructor to copy a Stack

Tags: java, data-structures, constructor, stack

Recently,I'm learing the **Algorithms 4th**,when I come to solve the problem that

> Create a new constructor for the linked-list implementation of *Stack.java* so that Stack t = new Stack(s) makes t reference a new and independent copy of the stack s.

Here is the *Stack.java*

```java
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
public class Stack<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
private Node<Item> first;     // top of stack
private int n;                // size of the stack
private static class Node<Item> {
    private Item item;
    private Node<Item> next;
}

/**
 * Initializes an empty stack.
 */
public Stack() {
    first = null;
    n = 0;
}
 public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == null;
}
public int size() {
    return n;
}
 public void push(Item item) {
    Node<Item> oldfirst = first;
    first = new Node<Item>();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldfirst;
    n++;
}
  public Item pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
    Item item = first.item;        // save item to return
    first = first.next;            // delete first node
    n--;
    return item;                   // return the saved item
}
private class ListIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {
    private Node<Item> current;

    public ListIterator(Node<Item> first) {
        current = first;
    }
 public boolean hasNext() {
        return current != null;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public Item next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Item item = current.item;
        current = current.next; 
        return item;
    }
}
```

> The answer of *Recursive solution* is that create a copy constructor for a linked list starting at a given Node and use this to create the new stack.

```
Node(Node x) {
item = x.item;
if (x.next != null) next = new Node(x.next);
}

public Stack(Stack<Item> s) { first = new Node(s.first); }
```

But what make me confused is how can I combine the above code to the *Stack.java* as its constuctor,how can I handle the Node? to create a new class Node??May someone could hep me:)

Comment: You note that `Node` is a private class inside `Stack`. You simply have to add the copy constructor to it.

Comment: What do you mean *"to create a new class Node"*? You already have a `Node` class, so just add the new node copy-constructor to it (and add the no-arg constructor, since you won't get it for free anymore).

Comment: You might go for cloning, deep copy

Comment: yep,as by Andreas said, I have build a constructor in the inner class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new class Node. The Node is the same for the old stack and the new stack 't'.

Currently you have one constructor in your `Stack` class `public Stack()`. You need to make another one that accepts a Stack, as you've done in your example, which then calls a method that copies the old elements to the new stack (recursively or iteratively). It sounds like homework so I don't think any code is appropriate (not sure of the rules in that regard).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code fragment I hava solved my problem

```
   private class Node{
    Item item;
    Node next;
    Node()    {  }                          //default constructor Node
    Node(Node x){
        item=x.item;
        if(x.next!=null) next=new Node(x.next);     
    }
}
public Stack(){                     //default constructor Stack
    first=null;
    N=0;        
}

public Stack(Stack<Item> s) {first=new Node(s.first); }
```

Comment: This is incorrect! You are trying to refer same Stack with two different head's